# What is a good name for a date, time, location type PHP class?

Tags: php, datetime, class-design

I am currently coding a library/framework to use in my future projects.  I am trying to decide on a good name for a date time type class.

Most likely I will be extending PHP's Datetime class, but add my own methods to it.  Some methods include:

- displaying dates and times in different formats
- getting list of time zone options
- setting users time zone
- getting users set timezone
- adjusting dates and times according to users time zone
- difference between 2 times/dates
- other similar date and time functions

Based on that, what would you name a class that had methods to do such tasks?

Because PHP has a **Datetime** class already, I believe I will have to name it something different?

#### Ideas

- Dateandtime.class.php
- dates.class.php

Ideas?

Comment: It probably also plays a role what naming scheme your other classes follow. Can you show some examples?

Comment: `dateTimePlus` or `dateTimeExtended` would be my two first natural suggestions.

Comment: Ok... at least two thirds of the features you enumrated are already implemented in DateTime or it's companion classes. Unless there's something special about it, which didn't make into your question, try not to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: DateTime2AvengeTheRevenger.  Or DT2ATR, 'cause that's Hollywood style.

Comment: Note that you're providing file names, not class names. The two are not the same thing.

Comment: Where comes the 'location' from the question title?

Comment: @Pekka so far the library type classes are simple... Router.class.php  Cache.class.php  Database.class.php  Language.class.php  Logger.class.php  Config.class.php, etc....

Comment: @xtofl 'location' should of been 'timezones'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `DateTimeHelper` fits for this.

You can name the file what you like, but keep it similar to the name of your class.  It's the class name that would cause problems, not the filename.

Answer (score 3):

What about these?

- `DateTime2`
- `DateTimeHelper`
- `DateTimeExt`
- `My_DateTime` (or another prefix)

Some inspired by Java classes:

- `DateUtils`
- `Calendar`

Comment: I especially like the name 'calendar'

Answer (score 2):

You can add your framework name as a prefix for your class names (i.e Zend_*)
You can use another naming convention - add a number after the class (i.e Datetime2.php)
Another idea is to add Helper/Manager as a suffix. It all depends on how you are going to se the class ;)

Comment: The prefix is a brilliant basic suggestion, as it also makes eady autoloading possible in a multi-library environment.  `MyFramework_Date` or `MyFramework_Datetime` would then be natural choices

Answer (score 1):

You said the class has something to do with location, so my thought was "GeoDateTime"

Answer (score 0):

If you're using namespaces (*PHP 5.3+ only*) why not:

```
namespace MyFramework;

class DateTime extends \DateTime 
{
    \\ ...
}
```

and then use it;

```
use MyFramework\DateTime;

$myDateTime = new DateTime();
```